# dojo: how to get the class name of a div from its id

Tags: dojo

How to get class name of a div if we know the id of that div.

I want to toggle the class name of that div.

if i know the current class i can easily change that to second one.

I need the solution in dojo framework.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`.hasClass()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hasClass.html) to determine if it has the one you are looking for, and `.addClass()` if it does not:

```
var div = dojo.byId('divid');
if (div.hasClass('classToRemove')) {
  div.removeClass('classToRemove');
  div.addClass('classToAdd');
}
else {
  // Switch them
  div.removeClass('classToAdd');
  div.addClass('classToRemove');
}
```

There is also [`.toggleClass()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/toggleClass.html#dojo-toggleclass) if you just need to switch a single class on and off, but I don't believe it supports toggling between two classes.